# Euclidean Geometry Equilateral Triangle Problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

ABC is a equilateral triangle with vertex A fixed and B moving in a given straight line. Find  the locus of C.

Though it is clear that being an equilateral triangle, the size of the triangle must not change but still I am not able to visualize the exact conditions. One more thing, is there any mathematical way (other than just visualizing) through which the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it should be obvious that if $A$ is a fixed vertex and $B$ moves in a straight line, then $AB$ cannot be constant.  Equivalently stated, if $A$ is fixed and $AB$ is constant, then the locus of $B$ is a circle with $AB$ as radius.

We conclude that the only reasonable interpretation of the question is to suppose $A$ is fixed and $B$ moves in a straight line, allowing the size of equilateral $\triangle ABC$ to vary as $B$ varies.

Under such an interpretation, the locus is one of two lines (depending on which triangle you choose), either of which forms an angle of $\pi/3$ with the given line along which $B$ moves.

[image]

To see why, we may assume without loss of generality that $A = (0,0)$ and $B = (2,2t)$ for some parameter $t \in \mathbb R$.  Then the locus of point $C = (x,y)$ corresponds to the solution of the system $$\begin{align*} x^2 + y^2 &= 4(1+t^2) \\ (x-2)^2 + (y-2t)^2 &= 4(1+t^2). \end{align*}$$  The difference of these equations gives $$4(x-1) + 4t(y-t) = 0,$$ or $$x = 1+t^2-ty.$$  Substituting into the first equation then gives $$4(1+t^2) = (1+t^2-ty)^2 + y^2 = (1+t^2)(1+(y-t)^2),$$ or $$(y-t)^2 = 3,$$ which gives us the pair of solutions $$(x(t),y(t)) = \left(1 \pm t \sqrt{3}, t \mp \sqrt{3} \right).$$  This of course describes a parametrization of the aforementioned pair of lines, which has Cartesian coordinates $$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(x-4), \quad y = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(x + 4).$$

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem without coordinate geometry? And further without assuming that $B$ moves along a vertical line?

Comment: How do I solve this in a pure geometric way?